# Probability of $3$ balls having different colors through $2$ people's choices

Tags: probability

> Ahmed has a bag contains $3$ red balls, $4$ green balls and Mohamed has another bag containing $5$ red balls, $3$ green balls and $2$ yellow balls. Ahmed takes two balls from his bag and Mohamed takes a ball from his bag . What is the probability that the $3$ balls have different colors.

My working :
$$(r , g , y )\times 6
=\frac{3}{7}\times \frac{4}{6}\times\frac{2}{10}\times6 $$

Is considering the permutations between Ahmed and Mohamed choice correct or I would only consider Ahmed's permutations so I multiply by $2$ instead of $6$?

Comment: Not following your calculation.  Why are you multiplying everything by $6$? Clearly $M$ must take a yellow (what probability?) and $A$ must take one red and one green (what probability?), now multiply.

Comment: Do you mean i should multiply by 2 instead of 6 ? @lulu

Comment: I can't follow your calculation.  I think the calculation I sketched is clear, no?

Comment: @lulu Do you get $1/16$ as the final probability?

Comment: @Ajay  Let's see...$\frac 2{10}$ for $M$ picking yellow, $\frac 37\times \frac 46\times 2=\frac 47$ for $A$ choosing red, green in either order, so $\frac 2{10}\times \frac 47=\frac 4{35}$ in the end.  How do you get $\frac 1{16}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do have $6$ permutations of the triple $(r,g,y)$, namely $rgy, ryg, gry, gyr, yrg, ygr$, but the probability of $y$ in all but $2$ ($rgy, gry$) is zero, so you only need to consider $(r,g,y) + (g,r,y)$.

Comment: So , if the other bag had yellow balls i would multiply by 6 ? @JMP

Comment: @HussienMohamed; no, because the distribution is different.